# HTTP redirecting to HTTPS automatically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, https, localhost

I am facing a problem in running my application in localhost, I added rewrite rule to my web.config to redirect all my http site to https because I added ssl certificate but that was for online version. In localhost I commented out my rewrite rule in web.config still it is redirecting my http://localhost to https://localhost due to which my site is not running locally and I am not able to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your solution?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: RatHat, Yes I did but it didnt worked

Comment: If you're running locally using IIS Express, it might be caching the original web.config; one way to be sure is put a syntax error into web.config and run the app...if you don't get an error, it's IIS Express caching that's the problem. You could also publish the app to your local IIS and inspect the web.config to make sure you really have commented this out :)

Comment: @StephenByrne I tried but it was not error in web.config however I fixed it by assigning a different port number to my localhost and it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Glad it's fixed. Given that worked I'd say it's probably your IIS Express cache.

Comment: Same error was on all browsers  or specific to chrome?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by a hit and trial method but it worked perfectly for me. What I did was that I changed the port number for example it was http://localhost:5722 previously I just changed the port number to http://localhost:5729 and it started working :)

Comment: Was this issue specific for chrome or for all browsers?

Answer (score 2):

**Browser put 301 in cache** : 
If you use "301 Moved Permanently" your browser (like Chrome and Firefox) put in cache with no expiry date that http://localhost need to be redirected to https://localhost.

To force browser re-fetch, you can :

- open your DevTools, check Disable cache ;
- clear you Browsing History
  cache ;

**To control cache from server :** If you want to control 301 cache from server you can use `Cache-Control` `Expires` http header.

**To cancel a 301 on server :** If you want do undo 301 on your website, just do another 301 to redirect back again : Your browser will re-fetch the old cached url  to confirm that the old redirect isn't still there.

**Change redirct type :** You can use 302 or 307 http redirect (no cache) but it's not [the best SEO practice](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)...

Answer (score 0):

try to rebuild the project, and make sure that you comment in the web.config like this example :

```
<!-- some text -->
```

hope this helps